# Changing ggplot graphs for comparison

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I produce these two graphs using p-values obtained from a pairwise.wilcox.test and the following script. My problem is that I want to have the same colour for the different breaks in both graphs for comparison purposes. I’m aware that the problem here is that in the first graph (Sum of ROH) I don’t have any value in the break (0.001,0.05]. However I want to force the graph to add this break in the legend and to have the same colour as the second graph (Mean ROH Size)

```
test.result$value<-cut(test.result$value, breaks=c(-Inf,0.001,0.05,1),right=T)

windows()
ggplot(data = test.result, aes(X1, X2, fill = value))+
ggtitle("Sum of ROH")+
xlab("")+
ylab("")+
geom_tile(aes(fill=test.result$value),color="white")+
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues", direction = -1,name="p-Val")+
theme_minimal()+ 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                               size = 12, hjust = 1))+
coord_fixed()
```

[image: first graph]

[image: second graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the levels of your factors to be the same.  You can add levels that don't exist.

For example

```
levels(test.result$value) = c("(-Inf,0.001]", "(0.001,0.05]", "(0.05,1]")
```

Then add `drop = FALSE` into your fill scale to keep the value in the legend.

```
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", direction = -1, drop = FALSE, name = "p-Val")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks